# Pandas dataframe manipulation with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I iterate through Pandas DataFrame field and fill null values with input from another field within the same data frame

[image]

My objective is to fill the na values in column y with corresponding values in column z

Comment: by using `df.fillna()` , though the question lacks details

Comment: Thanks very much for response.
Adding more details, I have a data frame link this one;

    `x y z

    1 a na

    2 b na

    3 c na

    4 na d

    5 na e

    6 na f``

My objective is to fill the na's in column b with corresponding values in column c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its best to avoid iterating through dataframes when it can be accomplished using vector expressions. Something like this should work, although it may need to be massaged a little for your specific case though.

```
# Set your dataframe
df = ... 

# Gets a boolean vector for positions where you have na in column b
nulls_in_b = df["b"].isna()

# Set the places where its null to values from column c 
df["b"].loc[nulls_in_b] = df["c"].loc[nulls_in_b]
```